# How to finding the longest substring common in oracle between rows?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

In my oracle database i want finding the longest substring common. 
Example:

```
\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername\a.txt
\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername\forlder1\a.txt
\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername\forlder1\folder2\a.txt
```

So i want the result is:

```
\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername\
```

Anybody have idea help me, thanks ?

Comment: Do you really need a substring in general terms? Or maybe just "starts with" substring is enough?

Comment: Why is it not `\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername\ `?

Comment: I want substring in general string.

Comment: According to your response, you don't want substrings in general, you need the longest shared parent directory (assuming that \root\dir1\dir\ refers to directories in a file system). For example, \roomname\nameid\dep and \roomname\nameid\department only share \roomname\nameid as directories but they share \roomname\nameid\dep as strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eef70/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE files ( name ) AS
SELECT '\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername\a.txt' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername\forlder1\a.txt' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername\forlder1\folder2\a.txt' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH names ( name ) AS (
  SELECT SUBSTR( name, 1, MIN( LENGTH( name ) ) OVER () )
  FROM   files
),
substrs ( common, num_matches ) AS (
  SELECT name,
         COUNT( DISTINCT name ) OVER ()     
  FROM   names
UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR( common, 1, LENGTH( common ) - 1 ),
         COUNT( DISTINCT SUBSTR( common, 1, LENGTH( common ) - 1 )  ) OVER ()     
  FROM   substrs
  WHERE  num_matches > 1
  AND    LENGTH( common ) > 1
)
SELECT common
FROM   substrs
WHERE  num_matches = 1
AND    ROWNUM = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eef70/1/0)**:

```
|                                              COMMON |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
| \roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername\ |
```

---

**Update** - if you want to restrict it to complete sub-folders then just truncate the output to the last `\` character:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/abc304/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE files ( name ) AS
SELECT '\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername\a.txt' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername\forlder1\a.txt' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername\forlder1\folder2\a.txt' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername_1\a.txt' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH names ( name ) AS (
  SELECT SUBSTR( name, 1, MIN( LENGTH( name ) ) OVER () )
  FROM   files
),
substrs ( common, num_matches ) AS (
  SELECT name,
         COUNT( DISTINCT name ) OVER ()     
  FROM   names
UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR( common, 1, LENGTH( common ) - 1 ),
         COUNT( DISTINCT SUBSTR( common, 1, LENGTH( common ) - 1 )  ) OVER ()     
  FROM   substrs
  WHERE  num_matches > 1
  AND    LENGTH( common ) > 1
)
SELECT SUBSTR( common, 1, INSTR( common, '\', -1 ) ) AS common
FROM   substrs
WHERE  num_matches = 1
AND    ROWNUM = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/abc304/1/0)**:

```
|                                   COMMON |
|------------------------------------------|
| \roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\ |
```

Comment: thanks you for help, but if i create table more foldername_1 the result only show `\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername\` i want show more the result `\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername_1\`. You can see my question below. THANKS SO MUCH

Comment: @John.D Updated

Comment: thanks, but i want get 2 result `\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername` `\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername_1`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [stats_mode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions154.htm) function, that takes as its argument a set of values and returns the value that occurs with the greatest frequency:

```
select stats_mode(field_name) 
  from table_name
```

returns

```
\roomname\nameid\department\foledertest\foldername\a.txt
```

Then, in this case, you could use something like a substring function to catch only the path:

```
select substr(common, 1, instr(common, '\', -1))
  from (select stats_mode(field_name) as common 
          from table_name);
```